# How do I tell if a variable is a valid array key?

Tags: php

I want to create a function that won't create errors if it's passed arguments that aren't valid array keys, and successfully check if the argument is set as a key in an array.

```
static function IsAwesome($name) {
    return isset(self::$_awesomeThings[$name]);
}
```

This creates a lovely message when someone passes, say, an object as $name:

```
Warning:  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in ...
```

What's the simplest way to avoid this behavior without excluding potentially valid keys, like `true`, for example? Assume existing code that can't be changed already relies on this behavior.

Comment: [gettype()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) and then rule out arrays and objects according to [PHP array documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Depends on what you want to do if not a valid type.  `is_string() || is_int()`.

Comment: BTW `false` will be cast to `0` and `true` to `1` so those really aren't valid.

Comment: @abracadaver I've seen you removed your comment, so I removed mine too. :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need something like:

```
static function IsAwesome($name) {
    return array_key_exists((string)$name, self::$_awesomeThings);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-exists.php